# Determine the strain energy of a bar

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures, energy

I have a Structures question about determining strain energy that I am unable to solve. **I have attempted it and I have the answer, I would appreciate if if someone can just tell me where I am going wrong.**

Q: A solid conical bar of circular cross-section is suspended vertically. The length of the bar is $L$, the diameter at the base is $D$ and the weight per unit volume is $\gamma$ (equivalent to density x gravity). Determine the strain energy of the bar due to its own weight.

$$\text{Answer} = U = \dfrac{\pi D^2 \gamma^2 L^3}{360E}$$

My work is as follows:

$$\begin{align}
U &= \dfrac{\gamma((1/3)\pi r^2 L)^2)L}{2E\pi r^2} \\
U &= \dfrac{\gamma(\pi^2r^4(1/9)L^2)L}{2E\pi r^2} \\
U &= \dfrac{\gamma\pi r^2L^3}{9\cdot2E} \\
U &= \dfrac{\gamma\pi(d^2/4)L^3}{18E} \\
U &= \dfrac{\gamma\pi d^2L^3}{18\cdot4E} \\
U &= \dfrac{\pi d^2 \gamma L^3}{72E} \\
\end{align}$$

I am incorrect by a factor of 1/5. Where in my working/logic did I go wrong?

I know:

$$U = \dfrac{(\rho gAL)^2L}{2EA}$$

I assume:

$$AL = \text{Volume (of a cone)} = (1/3)\pi r^2 h$$

I am confused as to whether the A in the denominator is the base of the
cone or the volume divided by the height.

I can derive the correct numerator, however I am not sure how my
lecturer arrived at 360E for the denominator.

Comment: This is an integration problem. The bar tapers to a cross-sectional area of zero at the top, and the *volumetric* strain energy changes throughout the length. Find the volumetric, differential strain energy in a small horizontal sliver of the bar with thickness *dz* (this will depend on the cross-section area at that point and the weight of the remaining bar underneath) and integrate that differential strain energy over the length of the bar.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your reply! Here is my new work. Unfortunately I am still not getting the correct answer.

Comment: U = integral from 0 to L: (((y * V)^2) / (2 * E * A)) * dx

Comment: V = (1/3) * pi * (r^2)

Comment: A = (pi * (r^2))

Comment: therefore: U = integral from 0 to L: (((1/9) * (y^2) * (pi^2) * (r^4) * (x^2)) / (2* E * pi * (r^2))) * dx

Comment: U = (((y^2) * (pi^2) * (r^4)) / (18 * E * pi * (r^2))) * [(x^3) / 3]

Comment: U = (((y^2) * (pi) * (r^2)) / (54 * E)) * (L^3)

Comment: subbing ((D^2)/4) for r gives: U = (((y^2) * (pi) * (d^2) * (L^3)) / (216 * E))

Comment: However I am still missing something, is there anyway you can let me know where I am going wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: (unfortunately I could not add in line spacing for the work, which made it near unreadable, therefore I entered in multiple comments).

Comment: Earlier I mentioned V = (1/3) * pi * (r^2), that was a typo. I meant V = (1/3) * pi * (r^2) * x. I just want to clarify in case that throws anyone off, it does not change the rest of my work.

Comment: I just edited your question to use MathJax for the math, which looks much nicer and is easier to understand. Note, however, that your final answer ends up with $\gamma$, not $\gamma^2$. This is because you left the $\gamma$ out of the initial squared section on the very first line. If you put it in there (as is should be, according to your own definition of $U$ at the bottom), everything works out. I didn't do it in my edit because I didn't want to change the actual content of your question. Please feel free to [edit] your question to correct this if it was a mere typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that the wide end of the cone is up, of course—otherwise the stress would go to infinity as the full weight of the cone is applied to a cross-sectional area that tapers to zero. (I incorrectly specified the opposite configuration in my comment above.)

Measure the coordinate $z$ from the bottom (i.e., from the tip of the cone). Then, the diameter at any location $z$ is $$D(z)=\frac{Dz}{L}.$$ Therefore, the corresponding area is $$A(z)=\frac{\pi D(z)^2}{4}.$$ The volume hanging underneath location $z$ is $$V(z)=\frac{\pi D(z)^2z}{12},$$ with corresponding weight $W=\gamma V(z)$ applied across the cross section. Therefore, the stress on any horizontal infinitesimal slice of thickness $dz$ at location $z$ is $$\sigma(z)=\frac{W}{A(z)},$$ and the volumetric strain energy within that slice is thus $$dU=\left(\frac{\sigma(z)^2}{2E}\right)A(z)dz,$$ where I've applied the linear elasticity result that the differential strain energy *per unit volume* can always be expressed as $du=\sigma\,d\epsilon=\frac{\sigma}{E}d\sigma$ by Hooke's Law, or, integrated, $u=\frac{\sigma^2}{2E}$. Now, integrate $dU$ from $z=1$ to $L$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance, you really helped me.